# How List<T> works with Dictionary<K, List<T>>?

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
var solutions = new Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<int, int>>>();

List<Tuple<int, int>> list = null;

var z = solutions.TryGetValue(sum, out list);
if (!z)
{
   list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
   solutions.Add(sum, list);
}

list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(a, b));
```

I don't understand why when I add element to list (last line) it change corresponding key-value in dictionary?

Comment: Because the value in the dictionary is just a reference to the list object... as is the value of `list`.

Comment: @AlexD: I think it's better not to talk about "by reference" here. I know what you mean, but there's a big difference between references being passed by value, and an argument being passed by reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, deleted ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't change key value pair in dictionary by adding element to list. You are changing the list. And dictionary is just holding reference to that list so it appears to change.